# BlueSky Statistics - how to load csv?

Tags: r, rgui

[image]

How to solve this?

I have R 4.2 installed, but I can't get Blue to read the directory. It only recognizes this:
Is that the problem? how to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

3 months ago, I installed the (Windows) version 10 with the R package which was included.
No problem to open CSV (I managed to open even a SQLite file using a few lines of R)

Actually, you can also access to the user manual online for free. There is also some information regarding the installation if I remember correctly.

This is to set the correct environment variables in Windows:

https://www.blueskystatistics.com/v/vspfiles/downloadables/Edit-Windows-Environment-Variables.pdf